# Regular Expression Not matching the value

Tags: python, regex

I have a file saving IP addresses to names in format

```
<<%#$192.168.8.40$#% %#@Name_of_person@#% >>
```

I read This file and now want to extract the list using pythons regular expressions

```
list=re.findall("<<%#$(\S+)$#%\s%#@(\w+\s*\w*)@#%\s>>",ace)
    print list
```

But the list is always an empty list..

can anyone tell me where is the mistake in the regular expression

`edit-ace` is the variable saving the contents read from the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$ is a special character in regular expressions, meaning "end of line" (or "end of string", depending on the flavour). Your regex has other characters following the $, and as such only matches strings that have those characters after the end, which is impossible.

You will need to escape the $, like so: `\$`

I would suggest the following regular expression (formatted as a raw string since you are using Python):

```
 r"<<%#\$([^$]+)\$#%\s%#@([^@]+)@#%\s>>"
```

That is, `<<%#$`, then one or more non-$ characters, `$#%`, a whitespace character, `%#@`, one or more non-@ characters, `@#%`, whitespace, `>>`.

Comment: so will it work if i try 
list=re.findall(r"<<%#$(\S+)$#%\s%#@(\w+\s*\w*)@#%\s>>",ace)

Comment: @Cyberzomie What's to stop you trying it to see if it works? :)

Comment: I tried it on the example in your question, and it returned `[('192.168.8.40', 'Name_of_person')]` (**EDIT:** "It" being my solution.)

Comment: @Cyberzomie `r"<<%#$(\S+)$#%\s%#@(\w+\s*\w*)@#%\s>>"` would have to be changed to `r"<<%#\$(\S+)\$#%\s%#@(\w+\s*\w*)@#%\s>>"`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
text = '<<%#$192.168.8.40$#% %#@Name_of_person@#% >>'
ip, name = [el[1] for el in re.findall(r'%#(.)(.+?)\1#%', text)]
```

If you can get any with just splitting on '@' and '$' then...

```
from itertools import itemgetter

ip, name = itemgetter(1, 3)(re.split(r'[@\$]', text))
```

You could also just use built-in string functions:

```
tmp = text.split('$')
ip, name = tmp[1], tmp[2].split('@')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

u use a invalid regex pattern.
you may use 
r"<\%#\$(\S+)\$#\%\s\%#@(\w+\s*\w*)@#\%\s>>" replace 
"<<%#$(\S+)$#%\s%#@(\w+\s*\w*)@#%\s>>" in fandall method

good luck~!